# Generic Inquiry Parent Child Relation

Tags: acumatica

I have been trying to pull up the data from Contract, ContractDetail, ContractItem and InventoryItem in Generic Inquiry. So, after adding up all 4 tables I created relationship as below.

[image]

The relationship between Contract and ContractDetail is fine. And now since ContractDetail uses ContractItemID, I have set the relationship as below. But it throws me error like this.

[image]

And, upon looking into the stack trace, I find the generated query looks this:

```
DECLARE @P0 SmallDateTime(4) SET @P0='9/27/2018 12:00:00 AM' DECLARE @P1 nvarchar(MAX) SET @P1='0' SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM ( 
    [Contract] InnerQuery_Contract 
    INNER JOIN ( 
        [ContractDetail] InnerQuery_ContractDetail_ContractDetail 
        INNER JOIN [Contract] InnerQuery_ContractDetail_Contract ON [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_Contract].CompanyID IN (1, 3) AND 32 = SUBSTRING([InnerQuery_ContractDetail_Contract].CompanyMask, 1, 1) & 32 AND [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_Contract].[DeletedDatabaseRecord] = 0 AND [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_ContractDetail].[ContractID] = [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_Contract].[ContractID] AND [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_ContractDetail].[RevID] = [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_Contract].[RevID] 
        LEFT JOIN 
            [ContractDetail] InnerQuery_ContractDetail_ContractDetailExt_ContractDetailExt 
         ON [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_ContractDetailExt_ContractDetailExt].[ContractID] = [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_ContractDetail].[ContractID] AND [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_ContractDetailExt_ContractDetailExt].[LineNbr] = [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_ContractDetail].[LineNbr] AND [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_ContractDetailExt_ContractDetailExt].[RevID] = [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_Contract].[LastActiveRevID] AND [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_ContractDetailExt_ContractDetailExt].CompanyID = 3 
    ) ON [InnerQuery_Contract].[ContractID] = [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_ContractDetail].[ContractID] AND [InnerQuery_ContractItem].[ContractItemID] = [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_ContractDetail].[ContractItemID] AND [InnerQuery_ContractDetail_ContractDetail].CompanyID = 3 
    INNER JOIN [ContractItem] InnerQuery_ContractItem ON [InnerQuery_ContractItem].CompanyID = 3 AND [InventoryItem].[inventoryID] =  [InnerQuery_ContractItem].[RecurringItemID] 
) 
WHERE [InnerQuery_Contract].CompanyID IN (1, 3) AND 32 = SUBSTRING([InnerQuery_Contract].CompanyMask, 1, 1) & 32 AND [InnerQuery_Contract].[DeletedDatabaseRecord] = 0 AND [InnerQuery_Contract].[UsrLockDate] < @P0 AND (CASE WHEN ([InnerQuery_Contract].[BaseType] = 'T' OR [InnerQuery_Contract].[BaseType] = 'R') THEN CONVERT (BIT, 1) ELSE CONVERT (BIT, 0) END) = @P1 OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
```

So, there is problem with Alias name for table in the query. So, how do I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Joins in Acumatica works exactly like in SQL. First build the query in SQL and get the result as to what you need and then try to construct the same in Generic Inquiry.

Apart from than, I do not see any relations between Contracts and Inventory. Please explain what you are trying to get.

Here is the way you should join your tables in Generic Inquiry

[image]

Comment: Contract and InventoryItem are not directly related. Contract and ContractDetail is related with ContractID. ContractDetail and ContractItem is related with ContractItemID. And ContractItem and InventoryItem is related by the field ContractItem.RecurringItemID  and InventoryItem.InventoryItemID.

Comment: These are the fields that I want to show up in the result grid.
https://imgur.com/a/8EEqPB0

Comment: I have modified my reply above.

Comment: I don't think we can set ContractDetail as parent and ContractItem as child (same with ContractItem and InventoryItem) since ContractItem is the one with Primary key field ContractItemID and used as a ForeignKey field in ContractDetail. And even if I try the above mentioned relationship I get this error.

https://imgur.com/a/ohhUvUQ

Comment: I tried to set the exact relation as per your answer. But I got the following error.
https://imgur.com/a/ZPvZh33
And this is the stack trace to that:
https://imgur.com/a/eTWCuFT

And the weird part is if I try to save that again, Parent table and Child table gets reversed back and ContractDetail becomes parent and Contract becomes child table.

Comment: I tried to create the generic inquiry with same tables and relations and it worked without any errors. I tried it in the 2018 R1 (18.112.0019) instance.

Should I do differently to make it work in 2018 R2?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WgTC8-kU5BF2xDO7dcwbjISeH_5R8cm6/view?usp=sharing